# dynamic array in C resizing

Tags: c, arrays

I've got a problem with dynamic array. I have to write a program which adds a character to dynamic array starting with 0 elements going to 10. I mustn't use realloc and I have to free the array each time.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

void add(int **ptab, int n, int new_elem)
{

    int *tab2, y;

    tab2 = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    for(y = 0; y < n; y++)
    {
        tab2[y] = (*ptab)[y];
    }
    *ptab = tab2;   
    (*ptab)[n] = new_elem;
    free(ptab);
}

main()
{
    int *ptab, i, x;

    *ptab = NULL;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        add(&ptab, i, x);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", ptab[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `*ptab = NULL;` --> `ptab = NULL;`, `tab2=malloc (n * sizeof(int));` --> `tab2=malloc ((n+1) * sizeof(int));`

Comment: function add() malloc, need to insert '+1' so will be room for an element to be added.  Otherwise this line: (*ptab)[n] = new_elem; is writing past the end of the allocated memory.   also when function add() parameter 'n' is 0, malloc returns NULL, so be sure to add the '+1' to the malloc.  Note: checking the returned value from malloc for successful operation would have caught that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*ptab=tab2;   
(*ptab)[n]=new_elem;
free(ptab);
```

should be

```
free(*ptab);
*ptab=tab2;   
(*ptab)[n]=new_elem;
```

Currently, you're overwriting the old array pointer before freeing it, so you no longer know what you're supposed to free.

Comment: Also, there is a tremendous difference between the original `free(ptab)` and this corrected version's `free(*ptab)`.